# Правильная сетка CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Нужно сделать правильную сетку с помощью CSS и желательно Flexbox.

Вот так у меня выглядит сейчас:

[image: Пример]

Что тут не так:

1. Нижняя часть сетки не прижата к левому краю.
2. Не изменяется расстояние между элементами.

Единственное, что тут правильно более менее, это то, что сетка размещается по центру блока. Но тут тоже свой подвох, нужно чтобы максимальная ширина левого и правого расстояния были 30-40px, а далее уже менялось расстояние между самими элементами сетки. Прошу помочь, а то уже куча вариантов попробовал.

Высота и ширина элемента сетки 100px и отступ 2px, максимальный отступ слева и справа от блока с сеткой элементов — 35px.

Comment: как я понял эти блоки вы извлекаете из базы данных?

Comment: @Ezdrael да, так и есть

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `display: inline-block` для элементов и для контейнера присвоить `text-align: justify;`. Минимальное расстояние реализуется через `padding`:

```css
.container {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #464646;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.container__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
</div>
```

Затем для последней строчки рассчитывайте отступы с помощью JavaScript при `resize`.

---

#### UPDATE

Для того, чтобы не было отступов между элементами и в последней строке элементы выравнивались по левому краю оберните блок ещё одним:

```css
.container {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #464646;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper-center {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container__item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper-center">
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <div class="container__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если избавиться от варианта с отступом между самими элементами сетки? А чисто по бокам и чтобы они прижаты к левому краю, такое возможно без js? Просто не охото его применять для такой задачи и если так возможно, то лучше уже так, но если нет, то спасибо за дополненный ответ, отмечу тогда его.

Comment: @100РОЖЬ Просто убираете для контейнера `text-align: justify;` и всё. Либо другой способ: для контейнера присваиваете `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` (в этом случае для элементов `display: inline-block;` факультативно).

Comment: и вот еще что тут не правильно, это padding, нужно не фиксированный всмысле, а так чтобы он менял размер пока не достигнет того, чтобы влез следующий элемент в строку, тоесть по сути нужна сетка элементов, но при изменении размера блока, чтобы отступ менялся не слева или справа, а с двух сторон, тоесть чтобы эта сетка по центру была

Comment: @100РОЖЬ Но при этом надо чтобы элементы на последней строчке были прижаты слева?

Comment: да, в этом собственно вся соль) тоесть по центру расположить просто, в моем примере я этого и добился, но так и не смог нижние перенести влево. Вот что-то можно с блоков в блоке придумать, но например inline-block становится по ширине родительского блока

Comment: @100РОЖЬ Смотрите обновление ответа. То что надо?

Comment: нет, немого не то, но уже близко к идеалу) а как же отступ слева и справа? Он не должен быть фиксированным, этот отступ должен изменяться, если элемент сетки не входит в строку

Comment: @100РОЖЬ Я немного не понимаю, что вам надо. Измениться как именно?

Comment: конкретно мне нужно то, чтобы сетка была в центре блока, и прижималась к левому краю, тоесть вот, изначально так |000|, сделал шире экран и блок расширился |  000  |, сделал еще шире, сетка стала шире |0000| и т д, сама задача решается легко, но при этом чтобы сетка прижималась к левому краю (самая нижняя строка, вы правильно это смогли отобразить)

Comment: @100РОЖЬ Я не совсем понимаю, в чём именно не подходит моё решение. Может кто-то другой вам поможет.

Comment: не подходит он тем, что padding 35px вот чем, такого не должно, тоесть отступ от основного блока должен быть как и от остальных 2px, я писал 35px когда имел ввиду, что это максимальное расстояние от края, а дальше уже идет изменение расстояния между самими элементами сетки

Comment: И этот вариант мы отбросили, и получается что нужно просто сетку расположить по центру (например внутренние сделать inline-block, а блоку дать text-al: center) и будет по центру сетка, НО нижние элементы тоже будут по центру (как на картинке в вопросе) а надо чтобы они прилипали к левой части, вот и все

Comment: @100РОЖЬ Я вас теперь понял. Дело просто в том, что у блока `.wrapper-center` ширина не будет принимать чётко значение контента и это поведение почти уверен, что не решить средствами CSS. Боюсь что вам придётся ли с этим смириться, либо решать это с помощью JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Если я вас правильно понял, то всё решается таким способом

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 312px;
  max-width: 370px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 3px solid #464646;
  background-color: black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto; 
}
.flexbox__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #464646;
}

/* Если блоков в конце 2 */
.flexbox__item:nth-child(3n+2):last-child {
  margin-right: calc(100% - 200px - ((100% - 300px) / 2));
}
/* Суть вычислений: от всей ширины отнимаем (количество блоков в конце умножить на ширину одного блока) и отнимаем (от общей ширины отнимает (максимальное количество блоков в конце умноженное на их ширину) и потом делим на колечество блоков размещённых в конце) */
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
</div>
```

К сожалению для `space-around` не знаю как сделать, так как не знаю, как высчитать размеры отступом по бокам

Comment: Классное решение, но маленько не то, так как этот блок с сеткой он расширяется с экраном вместе, тоесть он не ограничен 370px, и если его делать шире и увеличить число элементов допустим до 10 (А их там будет от 0 до бесконечности, смотря какое условие), то при масштабировании кошмар какой-то получается)

Answer (score 5):

#### 1) Попробуйте грид

На каждой строке поместится максимум блоков, последняя строка встанет по общему левому краю, а весь массив блоков выровняется по центру страницы.

Вот [короткое знакомство с гридами](http://bureau.ru/bb/soviet/20170622/). Вот [игра](http://cssgridgarden.com/) по их базовым свойствам.

Опера-мини [не поддерживает](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) грид. А Эксплорер и Эйдж поддерживают только старую версию гридов, которая настолько отличается от нынешней, что приведённым здесь решением воспользоваться не удастся. (Спасибо Вадиму Овчинникову [за комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615618/#comment1019924_687856).)

Решение взял [из этой статьи](http://css-live.ru/css/responsive-grid-css-grid-layout-auto-fill.html).

Чтобы блоки держались кучно по центру страницы, их родителю нужно свойство `justify-content: center;`: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/gRjmwd

Чтобы блоки заполняли страницу по ширине, а по краям оставался отступ, можно увеличить `padding` и поменять `justify-content` на `space-between`: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/YQjrZb

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #333;
  display: grid;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 100px);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.grid__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

#### 2) Инлайн-блоки и псевдо-элемент

На том же сайте есть [решение без флекса и грида](http://css-live.ru/articles/krasivoe-vyravnivanie-blokov-po-rezinovoj-setke.html). Понимаю его так:

1. Создаём в основном блоке псевдоэлемент из цепочки слов и пробелов. В качестве «псевдослова» используем букву `i`, потому что она самая тонкая и её размер легче предсказать: `content: 'i i i i i i i i i i';`.
2. Эти "псевдослова" дополнят собой последнюю строку. Поэтому последняя строка станет предпоследней, и её блоки начнут повторять расположение блоков в предшествующих строках. Чтобы это произошло, количества `i` должно хватить, даже если в строке окажется только один «настоящий» элемент.
3. С помощью `padding-left` и `word-spacing` добиваемся, чтобы каждое "псевдослово" занимало столько же места, сколько занимает «настоящий» блок с отступами.
4. Чтобы `i` не мозолили глаза, назначаем им `visibility: hidden;`.
5. Хвост из невидимых `i` добавляет вертикальный отступ в конце общего блока. Чтобы сделать его поменьше, задаём псевдоэлементу шрифт помельче. (Но не ноль, а то он не выполнит свою задачу.)

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/awjJxE

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #333;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.grid:after {
  content: ' i i i i i i i i i i i i ';
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1px;
  padding-left: 103px;
  visibility: hidden;
  word-spacing: 103px;
}
.grid__item {
  background: black;
  display : inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width : 100px; height: 100px;
  /* эмуляция inline-block для IE6-7*/
  //display : inline;
  //zoom : 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ :) Но а как же отступы между блоками?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Фиксированный паддинг по краям и `justify-content: space-between;` решают задачу? https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/YQjrZb

Comment: Ты - Бог :) Отредактируй ответ, добавив пример с codepen и если никто не предложит лучше решение - отмечу ваш ответ

Comment: Поменял решения для грида и инлайн-блоков. Оставил ссылку на "отцентрованный" грид как на доп. вариант.

Comment: Скажу сразу за `grid`-вёрстку для IE и Edge. Это невероятно дубовая штука. Она вообще другая, с новым синтаксисом общая только концепция. Для каждой клетки надо явно задавать расположение, по умолчанию абсолютно всё положится в самую первую ячейку, друг на дружку. Никакого автоматического расположения. Всё в вендорных префиксах. Имена свойств другие, и большая часть новых свойств (и соотвественно возможностей) вообще не имеет аналогов. [Хорошая статья по работе grid в IE](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Очень крутой ответ, грид здесь просто идеален. 1) А можете раскрыть магию второго способа? А то мне лично вообще не понятно за счёт чего это работает. 2) А можете так указать, что первый способ невозможно применить для IE и Edge, так как из формулировки "поддерживают только старую версию гридов" это не очевидно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Обновил ответ. Браузеры пишу по-русски, извините :)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky А если при втором способе будет разное кол-во элементов, придётся постоянно расчитывать свойства `.grid:after`?

Comment: Свойства поменяются, если поменяется ширина блоков. От количества блоков в строке свойства не должны зависеть. И, возможно, свойства поддаются точному расчёту, но это надо проверить.

Comment: Поздравляю с победой :)

Comment: @Yuri Спасибо за конкурс по интересной задаче. Если бы не конкурс, так бы и думал, что она не решается.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid {
    background-color: #333;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 0 30px;
    }

.grid__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
  <div class="container__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте так, этот вариант всегда держит одинаковое растояние блоков

Comment: Как только появляется вторая строка, блоки в ней собираются в центре, и получаем как раз, от чего нужно избавиться. Смотрите скриншоты в вопросе.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mario-web/pen/GEzyRR  - вот так подойдет посмотрите, автоматическое растояние между блоками и всегда по краям 30-40 px

Comment: Сейчас последняя строка заполняется по всей ширине. А задача, если правильно понимаю, в том, чтобы в последней строке блоки прижимались к левому краю и при этом повторяли рисунок остальных строк.